# jquery datatable whole column background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable, I want to color code the column based value in the last row.
If the TYPE value is "O" then apply yellow color, otherwise nothing. My columns are dynamic.

expected result:

[image]

```
 var dt=  $(element).dataTable({
            deferRender: true,
            destroy: true,
            "aaData": data, // data is coming from service
            "aoColumns": columns // column is dynamic
        });
```

Comment: post the html and js

Comment: see ,the question with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) to handle table draw event and enumerate columns data with [`columns().every()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns%28%29.every%28%29) to find columns containing required values and highlight them.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    drawCallback: function(){
       var api = this.api();

       api.columns().every( function () {
          var data = this.data();

          if($.inArray('O', data) !== -1){
             $(this.nodes()).addClass('highlight');
          } else {
             $(this.nodes()).removeClass('highlight');
          }
       });
    }
});
```

Please note that the code above detects `O` in all rows. To handle only the last row you need to add more code.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tf70z0L5/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [rowCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback)

```
$(element).dataTable({
    "rowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
        switch(aData[0]){
            case 'O':
                $(nRow).css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
                //also style other rows here
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Simple demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p88MP/1/)

Comment: I don't want to style row, I want to style the whole column if a cell with TYPE = "O" exist on that column.

Comment: You could hack on that, notice that aData[0] indicates first column